# Custom UITableViewCell hides half of the delete button when gradient is applied

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Situation:

1.) I have created my custom table view cell

2.) I override the `layoutSubViews` method and in this method I apply the gradient for each cell

3.) Now if I click the (-) button then the 'delete' button appears but only half of the button is visible.

Code:

```
var gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = (self.subViews.first?.frame)!
gradient.colors = [UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor]
self.subViews.first?.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
```

Question:

When I tap the (-) button the `layoutSubView` function is not getting called. So the gradient bounds are not updated. I think this might be the reason.

Comment: Do you have any alpha change in the gradient?

Comment: @Laffen I am not using any Alpha change.

Comment: Try changing 'gradient.frame = (self.subViews.first?.frame)!' to 'gradient.frame = (self.subviews.first?.bounds)'

Comment: @Laffen Its not working

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any auto-layout issues?

Comment: @Laffen  Yes. I am sure. And one more point I want to mention here is, If i removed this gradient effect then I am the full 'Delete' button is visible. If I apply the gradient using my above code then only this problem is coming.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
   super.layoutSubviews()
   //add gradient here
}
```